# python-shell from Node.js not executing python scripts

Tags: python, node.js

I'm trying to learn JavaScript. Was previously coding in Python. I like to link some of my Python programs to run in conjunction with Node.js. Using codes from python-shell to run my Python scripts but encountered the following error which I can't even begin to understand:

```
/Users/cadellteng/AtomProjects/useSpawn/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:217
                return callback(err);
                       ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at PythonShell._endCallback (/Users/cadellteng/AtomProjects/useSpawn/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:217:24)
    at terminateIfNeeded (/Users/cadellteng/AtomProjects/useSpawn/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:158:39)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/cadellteng/AtomProjects/useSpawn/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:131:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:316:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
```

I'm only trying to run a simple node and python script containing 5 and 2 lines respectively. Please see my code below and let me know if I'm doing anything wrong:

usingPythonShell.js

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');

PythonShell.run('hello.py', () => {
  console.log('finished');
});
```

hello.py

```
name = input('What is your name?\n>>> ') # John Doe
print('Hello '+ name +'!') # expects output as 'Hello John Doe!'
```

I tried to put my python inside a `main()` and it doesn't seem to work as well.

I'm confident the python script works because it executed fine when I executed it from the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell#running-a-python-script-with-arguments-and-options).

The arguments to `PythonShell.run` are a script name, an options object, and a callback. So the callback is the third argument.

In your case you pass the callback where the options should be. The third argument remains `undefined`, and indeed it's not a function.